# Gnome-Shell: undefined symbol: gvc_channel_map_get_type

Tags: gnome-shell, linux-from-scratch

I am trying to compile Gnome-Shell-40.5 on my LinuxFromScratch box, but keeping getting the following error:

```
/usr/src/gnome-shell-40.5/build/tmp-introspectr58mnoox/Gvc-1.0: symbol lookup error: /usr/src/gnome-shell-40.5/build/tmp-introspectr58mnoox/Gvc-1.0: undefined symbol: gvc_channel_map_get_type
Command '['/usr/src/gnome-shell-40.5/build/tmp-introspectr58mnoox/Gvc-1.0', '--introspect-dump=/usr/src/gnome-shell-40.5/build/tmp-introspectr58mnoox/functions.txt,/usr/src/gnome-shell-40.5/build/tmp-introspectr58mnoox/dump.xml']' returned non-zero exit status 127
```

Do you have any idea, what I could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stated which version of (B)LFS you're building.

As of this writing, the current stable Beyond Linux From Scratch is Version 11.0.

Currently, the supported gnome-shell version is 40.4:

https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/11.0/gnome/gnome-shell.html

(And the same is true for the latest Development snapshot, r11.0-81.)

You'll likely have better luck if you follow the BLFS build instructions, and satisfy the dependencies.

As a side note, `gvc_channel_map_get_type` appears to be defined in `libgnome-volume-control`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, I was using BLFS 11.0 and the 40.4 vs 40.5 was a mistake due to some experimenting on my side.
Actually, just found an answer. Not managing to compile gnome-shell yet, but got a huge step further.
libgvc is also build by Graphviz, but same name different library. That was already installed and caused this issue. Removing the Graphviz libgvc resolved it.